# Bash script to Edit all

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for, so I figured I'd ask. I'm looking for a way to do the following:

1. Scan a Directory Containing numbered directories (25-109)
2. Scan the directories inside of those numbered directories
3. Find the line in all files named "map.inp" containing the text: "MAP_93=   A   93 A"
4. Change all occurrences to "MAP_93=   A   93 V"

Normally I would do this manually, but there are roughly one thousand files to edit each within their own directory. I found a linux scheme to achieve this, but I'm not sure how to use a Bash script that has the same functionality. The files to be modified all have the same name, map.inp.

The pathways are all within the directory jan10, but in subdirectories like this:

```
/user/jan10/100/100A/map.inp
/user/jan10/99/99A/map.inp
```

etc.

The linux scheme I found would work like this:

```
 find /user/jan10/ \
 name map.inp \
 exec sed -i~ 's/MAP_93=   A   93 A\+/MAP_93=   A   93 V/' {} \;
```

The desired input would then be:

```
MAP_89=   A   93 A
```

And the output:

```
MAP_93=   A   93 V
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I apologize if this was unclear,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add `-` before `name` and `exec` parameters in the above mentioned `find` command.

```
find /user/jan10/ -name "map.inp" -exec sed -i 's/MAP_89=   A   93 A\+/MAP_93=   A   93 V/' {} \;
```

Comment: and careful with the spaces when using it in the sed regex part.